# CSV Import with custom Identity Part Separator in RavenDb

Tags: csv, ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm preparing a `csv` file to be imported into RavenDb, and have a column named `Raven-Entity-Name` to specify into which collection the documents have to be imported.

This data will be used by an ASP.NET MVC app, and so that RavenDb's default identity part separator (`/`) doesn't wreck havoc with my routes, I define a custom one on  my app's start-up:

```
DocumentStore.Conventions.IdentityPartsSeparator = "-";
```

The `csv` import actually generates id's using the default separator, is there a way I can specify a custom IdentityPartsSeparator when importing a csv file or is manually generating the id's on the csv file the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. You need to load the csv file using your code to control that.